# NGINX domain name prevent www redirect

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, forge

I am using laravel forge with nginx and am trying to display the domain as www.example.com rather than example.com

On some older configurations on my account I am able to display the content on both versions of the url however recently when I configure a site it redirects the www. version to the root version. Is there anyway to disable this behaviour.

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name .www.example.com .example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/site/web;
    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate
    # ssl_certificate_key
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;
    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;
```

Comment: Your question is `Is there anyway to disable this behaviour` and the answer to that question is **yes, there is a way**. Why did I type this response like this? I did it so you can see what happens when you ask for help and you provide no code. Make required amends to your question in order to get an answer that you can use.

Comment: @Mjh your point has been noted, I added in the code, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your site with the url www.example.com rather than example.com to achieve the url structure you desire.